# Multiplying single precision float with 2

Tags: c, floating-point, bit-manipulation

This is a homework question. I already found a lot of code online, including some code in StackOverflow. But I just want the concept not the code. I want to implement it myself. So the function I want to implement is:

- `float_twice` - Return bit-level equivalent of expression `2*f` for floating point argument `f`.
- Both the argument and result are passed as `unsigned int`'s, but they are to be interpreted as the bit-level representation of single-precision floating point values.

I want to know how to do this. I know floating point representation. And read wiki page on how to multiply two floats, but didn't understand it. I just want to know the concept/algorithm for it.

## Edit:

Thanks everyone. Based on your suggestions I wrote the following code:

```
unsigned float_twice(unsigned uf) {
    int s = (uf >> 31) << 31;
    int e = ((uf >> 23) & 0xFF) << 23;
    int f = uf & 0x7FFF;

    // if exponent is all 1's then its a special value NaN/infinity
    if (e == 0xFF000000){
        return uf;
        
    } else if (e > 0){  //if exponent is bigger than zero(not all zeros', not al 1's, 
                        // then its in normal form, add a number to the exponent
        return uf + (1 << 23);
        
    } else { // if not exponent not all 1's and not bigger than zero, then its all 
             // 0's, meaning denormalized form, and we have to add one to fraction

        return uf +1;
    } //end of if
    
} //end of function
```

Comment: One component of a float represents a power of two. That's the part you should be interested in.

Comment: If you know how the representation works, try some example `f` and compare its encoding with that of `2*f`. Multiplication of arbitrary floating point numbers is way more complicated than just multiplying by 2, so it probably doesn't matter if you have troubles understanding the former for now.

Comment: A good start might be to `printf()` out the bit pattern of `f` and `2 * f`.

Comment: The exponent section of the number is a power of two; multiply by two means incrementing that value by one, worrying about overflow becoming an infinity, NaN staying NaN, and zero staying zero.

Comment: Note that you'll need to special-case denormals.

Comment: The denormal case doesn't double the value -- it just bumps it up by epsilon (the smallest possible float value > 0).  To double it you want `(uf << 1) | s`

Comment: In addition -- your `e == 0xFF000000` test will never be true -- it should be `e == 0x7f800000`.  You also need to check for a non-inf exponent that will become Inf/NaN when you add 1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this (although some would claim that it breaks strict-aliasing rules):

```
unsigned int func(unsigned int n)
{
    float x = *(float*)&n;
    x *= 2;
    return *(unsigned int*)&x;
}

void test(float x)
{
    unsigned int n = *(unsigned int*)&x;
    printf("%08X\n",func(n));
}
```

In any case, you'll have to assert that the size of `float` is equal to the size of `int` on your platform.

---

If you just want to take an `unsigned int` operand and perform on it the equivalent operation of multiplying a `float` by 2, then you can simply add 1 to the exponent part of it (located in bits 20-30):

```
unsigned int func(unsigned int n)
{
    return n+(1<<20);
}
```

Comment: OP wants bit-level manipulation i think. he just needs to shift the bits representing exp.

Comment: @mafso: Oh, OK, I'll remove it then.

Comment: Just leave it.  It shows the OP how to print the bit patterns for a few numbers to get an idea where to start as mafso and I have suggested to him.

Comment: But I'd change `int` to `uint32_t` and `%u` to `%08X`.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Updated the answer to what OP might be looking for (after reading the comments above, implying that I might have misunderstood the question). In addition, I agree about the `"%X"` (already changed it earlier). Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos if i do that, what about if the number is in a denomralized form?

Comment: To multiply a subnormal (denormalized) floating point number with 2, you'll need to shift all bits of the mantissa one to the left.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: Hmmmm... A `union` would actually be quite a good idea for the first part of my answer. I keep "forgetting" that option for some reason (probably because I hardly ever use it). In any case, I think that what OP really wanted is in the second part of the answer, in which a `union` is not really needed (unless you want to verify the correctness of the operation).